# How to get the post date under the post title?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get my post date shown under the post title. I have tried different things but with no succes.

I was wondering what I should change to this code to get the post date under the post title. This is my my `index.php`:

```
<?php
$edgt_blog_type = milieu_edge_get_archive_blog_list_layout();
milieu_edge_include_blog_helper_functions( 'lists', $edgt_blog_type );
$edgt_holder_params = milieu_edge_get_holder_params_blog();

get_header();
milieu_edge_get_title();
?>

<div class="<?php echo esc_attr( $edgt_holder_params['holder'] ); ?>">
    <?php do_action( 'milieu_edge_action_after_container_open' ); ?>

    <p>This article was published on: <?php the_time('m/j/y g:i A') ?></p>

    <div class="<?php echo esc_attr( $edgt_holder_params['inner'] ); ?>">
        <?php milieu_edge_get_blog( $edgt_blog_type ); ?>
    </div>

    <?php do_action( 'milieu_edge_action_before_container_close' ); ?>
</div>

<?php do_action( 'milieu_edge_action_blog_list_additional_tags' ); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not in the loop, try using 
`<?php echo get_the_time( $format, $post ); ?>` 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time

Comment: Where should i put that in the file. Sorry i’m quit new to PHP wordpress.

Comment: You're using this `<?php the_time('m/j/y g:i A') ?>`. This only echos out to the screen if you are in the Wordpress loop as it uses the global $post object.  If you're not in the Wordpress loop (and I don't see any signs that you are / or are not) then you have to tell WP which post you want the time for. So replace the line you're using with the one I posted  `<?php echo get_the_time( 'm/j/y g:i A', $post ); ?>` and replace $post with your current $post or $post->ID. Again, to clarify, I don't know if you're in the loop or not. But it is an easy try and see :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your code but it did not work. Did i Do Something wrong with the code or am i nog in the loop or place it in the right file/place. This is what i tried = <?php echo get_the_time( 'm/j/y g:i A', $post ); ?>, <?php echo get_the_time( 'm/j/y g:i A', $post->ID ); ?>, <?php echo get_the_time( 'm/j/y g:i A', $4931 ); ?>, <?php echo get_the_time( 'm/j/y g:i A', $post->4931 ); ?>

Comment: Ok. It won't do to hard code the post id in dynamic code so let's consider this: where are you getting the other code from? Those are theme specific template tags you are using (that begin with milieu_) so I would suggest you try to find a template tag created by the theme for displaying the post time. If you can't find that (and I suspect it's there), maybe try this. put the line `<?php global $post; ?>` before `<?php echo get_the_time( 'm/j/y g:i A', $post ); ?>` If that doesn't work, I can't help you as you're not showing enough code to know what I'm working with. Good luck!